# doctrine subquery with custom SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm

im startin with Symfony and im trying to have all movie list and thier AVG rate il a grid dispaly.

My Query works fine on mySQL but not on Symfony

```
 SELECT m.id
FROM AppBundle:Movie AS m
LEFT JOIN (

SELECT AVG( rate ) AS avg_rate, movie_id
FROM AppBundle:Rate
)r ON m.id = r.movie_id
```

Whene i run it:

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT m.id, avg_rate
        FROM AppBundle:Movie AS m
        LEFT JOIN ( SELECT AVG( rate ) AS avg_rate, movie_id
        FROM AppBundle:Rate
        ) AS r ON m.id = r.movie_id');
$movies = $query->getResult();
```

i got this error :

> SELECT AVG(': Error: Class '(' is not defined.

[Here are my Mysql Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3NgVr.png)

Can you help please?
Thanks

Comment: This query compiles ? with out a group by clause?

Comment: Yes ! i added a screen shot of it .

Comment: AVG is not supported out of the box by D2: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#inheritance-mapping You will need to create your own extension http://www.doctrine-project.org/2010/03/29/doctrine2-custom-dql-udfs.html or find a bundle that slready implements it.  Or use SQL instead of DQL.

Comment: For advanced queries that uses SQL functions that are not supported by Doctrine you could use the Native SQL class: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class

Comment: ok thanks, im gonna try this !

Answer (score 0):

In fact, with ORM Doctrine, we have many relations between the entities :

- OneToMany
- ManyToMany
- OneToOne

With these relations, you could use `->join()`and `addSelect()` to add the another condition in the table of the second entity. Brief, one example :

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('m'); // m : movie
$qb->select('m')
    ->innerJoin('m.rates', 'r')
      ->addSelect('r')
      ->andWhere('r.rate = :rate')
      ->setParameter('rate', $rate) // $rate = value which you want
```

> I recommend you to use`->select(), ->innerJoin()`rather than the **raw request** like you used. It's clearer for me, so you can see the document in here : [query-builder-ormDoctrine](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html).